# Bootstrap overlapping input fields

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and right at the beginning, I end up having a problem.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h1>Lettergrepen oef-en-en</h1>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-heading -->

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- begin form -->
                        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span><strong><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></div></strong></span></button></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="wordExercise" name="Huisarts" value="Huisarts" disabled style="background-color: white;"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="Huis"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="arts"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="extra"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span><strong>+</strong></span></button></div>
                            </div> <!-- end of first row -->
                        </form>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-body -->          
                </div>      <!-- end panel-primary -->
            </div>      <!--end panel-group -->
        </div>      <!--end container -->
</body>
```

the code you see is bootstrap and a few HTML inputs, but when I checked my site I noticed the input fields are overlapping. When I used `margin: X X X X` to solve this I found out the front end may look good, but their position is still their old position (before using margin) and it somehow overlaps the old position input field and therefore I only have a bit of my input field that's able to be clicked on (to target the input field to write in). any idea how to solve this problem? I thought bootstrap would basically solve it, but it didn't. I wanted to give my input fields a font-size of 110% and a padding of 5px by 5px. So do bare in mind this also plays a part.

so far my css code used for it

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel-heading {
text-align: center;
}

.wordExercise {
text-align: center;
outline: none !important;
padding: 5px 5px;
font-size: 110%;
}

.btn {
margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
display: inline-block;
outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please paste as a snippet so we could see it ourselves

Comment: ahh crap.. how do I post a snippet? I'm quite new to this site. sorry.

Comment: try to add class="form-control" into each input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to give your inputs `width:100%` so that they fit to the columns sizes, and then perhaps style a bit your other classes like give `.col-sm-2{padding:0;}` or whtever else to fit your liking:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel-heading {
text-align: center;
}

.wordExercise {
text-align: center;
outline: none !important;
padding: 5px 5px;
font-size: 110%;
}

.btn {
margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
display: inline-block;
outline: none !important;
}

input{
  width:100%;
  padding:5px;
}

.row .col-sm-2{
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h1>Lettergrepen oef-en-en</h1>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-heading -->

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- begin form -->
                        <form class="container-fluid" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span><strong><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></div></strong></span></button></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="wordExercise" name="Huisarts" value="Huisarts" disabled style="background-color: white;"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="Huis"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="arts"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="extra"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span><strong>+</strong></span></button></div>
                            </div> <!-- end of first row -->
                        </form>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-body -->          
                </div>      <!-- end panel-primary -->
            </div>      <!--end panel-group -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Bad practice to implement yourself features that are already implemented in framework you use (padding 0 in that case)

Comment: i don't use bootstrap often enough to know it's classes but I agree with you in general

Comment: I want to note the code he gave indeed did help, but if I were to add padding to the 3 input fields underneath the "Huisarts" input (with padding 5px by 5px aswell) it will still overlap, could anyone explain how to avoid these overlaps? I appreciate the fact that u guys provided the code and stuff, but I would like to know how to do it myself in the future aswell. I would like to know how to create space between the first input field and the other 3. the 3 being aligned is perfect, but I would like to have a margin between the first and the second input field.

Comment: @dominus I edited the snippet to consider the padding, it doesn't seem to be overlaping correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @MateuszJ it worked, thank you very much. Could u give a quick explaination of why ur code is working and mine not? what was it that I didnt do for it to behave like I wanted ? how can I add some margin between the first and second input by the way? without it overlapping other content (the main problem basically)

Comment: @dominus In your code, you have specified `width` of the columns by giving them classes you wanted, but the inputs inside the columns don't have specified `width` and so they use some default value. By giving them `width:100%` you make them have 100% width of their parent which in this case is the width specified by `col-sm-2`. Then I removed the padding which as Sergey mentioned could have be done in a better way to remove spacing between the columns and then added your padding.

Comment: aha, thank you very much. found some very usefull tips and tricks in this section. Thank you all very much guys! I appreciate the time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add `class="form-control"` into each `<input>`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h1>Lettergrepen oef-en-en</h1>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-heading -->

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- begin form -->
                        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span><strong><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></div></strong></span></button></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="wordExercise form-control" name="Huisarts" value="Huisarts" disabled style="background-color: white;"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="Huis" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="arts" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="extra" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span><strong>+</strong></span></button></div>
                            </div> <!-- end of first row -->
                        </form>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-body -->          
                </div>      <!-- end panel-primary -->
            </div>      <!--end panel-group -->
        </div>      <!--end container -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `border-box` is by default in bootstrap so there is no need to write it yourself. `text-center` is a bootstrap class to align text center. `d-inline-block` is a bootstrap class for `display: inline-block`.

Try to use as less rules as possible (rules which are included in bootstrap already).

One more tip - camelCase is not in use in CSS by recommended standards.

Do not nest `block` inside `inline` as you nested `div` inside `span`.

https://jsfiddle.net/g7vnk9z9/8/

I hope it is what you wanted. You missed `form-group` wrapper for inputs and `form-control` for inputs themselves.